# Z3 does not solve quantifier expression, expression is sat

Tags: z3, smt

Using z3 v 4.8.1 - - 64 bit - build hashcode 016872a5e0f6 the script below evaluate to `unsat` but an result of `sat` is expected.

- Does z3 support solving expression like these?
- Can a different smt-solver solve expression like these?

  ```
  (set-option :print-success false)
  (set-logic ALL)
  (push 1)
  (declare-const ss1 Int)
  (declare-const ss3 Int)

  (assert (forall ((t_ss3 Int)(t_ss1 Int))
  (=>
    (< t_ss1 t_ss3)
    (and (and
     (< ss1 ss3)
     (= t_ss1 ss1))
     (= t_ss3 ss3))
  )))
  (echo "Check if the P -> Q is satisfiable")
  (check-sat)
  (pop 1)
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 is correct here; the script as you posed is indeed `unsat`. Here's what you said:

- Let there be two constants `ss1` and `ss3`
- For all integers `t_ss3` and `t_ss1`, whenever `t_ss1 < t_ss3` holds, it must be the case that:

  - `ss1 < ss3`
  - AND, `t_ss1` equals `ss1`
  - AND, `t_ss3` equals `ss3`

This is clearly not true for all `t_ss1` and `t_ss3`. There is no `ss1` and `ss3` that would satisfy this for *ALL* `t_ss1` and `t_ss2`. You only need to look at the very last clause: You can't expect all `t_ss3` to equal an arbitrary `ss3`.

I suspect you're trying to express some other property; but you did not code it correctly. Maybe you were trying to say if `t_ss1` equals `ss1` and `t_ss3` equals `ss3`, and `t_ss1  < t_ss3`, then `ss1 < ss3`? That would be coded like the following:

```
(declare-const ss1 Int)
(declare-const ss3 Int)

(assert (forall ((t_ss3 Int) (t_ss1 Int))
        (=> (and (< t_ss1 t_ss3)
                 (= t_ss1 ss1)
                 (= t_ss3 ss3))
            (< ss1 ss3))))

(check-sat)
```

and would indeed produce `sat`.

If you come up with a better description of what you're trying to express, you can get better help in modeling it in SMT-Lib in a different question.